# Update records using rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :queue => :environment do
  puts "Updating feed..."
  @books = Book.all
  @books.update_queue
  puts "done."
end
```

I have the above code in a file called `scheduler.rake` located in lib/tasks. When I run `rake queue` I get:

```
Updating feed...
rake aborted!
undefined method `update_queue' for #<Array:0x007ff07eb3ffd0>
```

That method is defined in my Books model as such:

```
def update_queue
    days_gone = (Date.parse(:new_books.last.created_at.to_s) - Date.today).to_i

    unless days_gone > -7
        new_book = self.user.books.latest_first.new_books.last
        new_book.move_from_queue_to_reading
        user.books.reading_books.move_from_reading_to_list
    else
        self.user.books.create(:title => "Sample book", :reading => 1)
    end
  end
```

Is this just not accessing the books and that's why it's giving me this undefined error? What am I doing wrong here? I simply want to update each book record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, you can't run an instance method on an array. `Book.all` returns an array of all items in your books table. You will need to loop through each instance in the array for this to work. You can do this one of two ways.

With standard block syntax:

```
@books.each do |book|
  book.update_queue
end
```

or by using the [send method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
Book.all.each.send(:update_queue)
```

Either way should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. So I looped through them like your first block of code, then it tells me that 'last' is undefined. ```days_gone = (Date.parse(:new_books.last.created_at.to_s) - Date.today).to_i``` Is there a better way to write that using something else to get the latest one instead of 'last'?

Comment: Where is the `:new_books` symbol coming from? `last` is an array method, and apparently `:new_books` is not an array. If `:new_books` is supposed to be a variable storing that array, you should not use symbols as variable names.

Comment: ```:new_books``` is a scope method. ```scope :new_books, lambda {|created_date|
    {:conditions => "created_at > '#{created_date}'"}
  }```

Comment: Scopes are simple methods called on classes, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes. Therefore you should be calling, `Book.new_books.last`.